# Tab multiline variable to heredoc

Tags: bash, markdown, eof, heredoc

I'm trying to add a multiline variable into a heredoc that will be put into a markdown file.

My script looks like this:

```bash
markdown=$(cat <<-EOF
<details>
    <summary>TEST</summary>

    ${output}
</details>
EOF
)

echo "$markdown" >> test.md
```

Where `output` is a multi line string:

```
this
is a
multiline
string
```

When I run the script the output looks like:

```
<details>
    <summary>TEST</summary>

    this
is a
multiline
string
</details>
```

How can I get it so that not just the first line of the output variable is tabbed correctly? I've tried running the variable through sed and adding tabs, but that doesn't work

Comment: So why did you use `-` in `-EOF` if you want to preserve the tabs?  You want tab - specifically horizontal horizontal character - or do you want to _indent_ the output? Markdown uses spaces, I do not think it uses tabs.

Comment: When you say "Tab" and "tabbed" in your question, do you actually mean "Indent" and "indented"? It makes a big difference for here-documents with a `-` before the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to indent it. Yourself. For example, add 4 spaces in front of every line by using sed:

```
cat <<-EOF
<details>
    <summary>TEST</summary>

$(sed 's/^/    /' <<<"$output")
</details>
EOF
```

You could replace newlines with a newline and 4 spaces:

```
cat <<-EOF
<details>
    <summary>TEST</summary>

    ${output//$'\n'/$'\n'    }
</details>
EOF
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want leading tabs treated literally then don't tell the shell not to treat them literally, i.e. remove the `-` you had added before the first EOF:

```
cat <<EOF
    whatever
EOF
```

Not the problem you asked about but don't populate a variable from a here doc then echo it to a file, just redirect the `cat` output to a file:

```
cat <<EOF > file
    whatever
EOF
```

or if you want to store the text in a variable then don't use a here-doc:

```
markdown="<details>
    <summary>TEST</summary>

    $output
</details>"

printf '%s\n' "$markdown" > file
```